# Why arent these web pages getting processed by PHP?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, ubuntu-14.04

I have created a fresh install of `nginx` and `php5-fpm` on an Ubuntu 14.04 server and made the changes shown below to get configuration working.
When I browse to a directory containing an `index.php` or try to browse to a `phpinfo.php` file, the browser tries to download the file (i.e. PHP is not processing the file and returning response).
If I browse to any other php files, e.g. `process.php` or `test.php` it runs fine.

#### Config

updated `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` to listen for TCP socket

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

file: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

file: /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        root /home/user/www;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        autoindex on;
        server_name _;
        error_page 404 /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                # Try a document root
                root /home/user/www

                # try_files $uri =404;
                #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

                # With php5-cgi alone:
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

When the error (download rather than process page occurs) Nothing shows
when `tail -f`'ing log files:

- `/var/log/php5-fpm.log`
- `/var/log/nginx/error.log`
- `/var/log/nginx/access.log`

What is wrong with this config?

Answer (score 1):

Your `location ~ \.php$` has `root /home/user/www`, which is unnecessary, since the same `root` is already defined on the server level. The definition also misses the semicolon.

So, remove the extra `root` definition and see if it helps.

Comment: good point, but it didnt make any difference , thanks

Answer (score 0):

try put move line

```
include fastcgi_params;
```

from the last to the first in block

```
location ~ \.php$ {
```

becuase it will reload default params so your customized param will be replaced

Comment: thanks, it didnt fix it though